# "File is too large to open" while opening crash dump on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, postmortem-debugging

I get "File is too large to open" error while trying to open a crash dump in VS 2017. Followings are my box specification:

- OS: Win 2012 R2 64Bit
- VS Enterprise 2017. its a clean installation without selecting any option while installing.
- Dump file is created by "procdump64  -ma -e 231532" command from a .Net 4.5 web application. Crash dump file size is about 9GB.

I really appreciate if someone could advise me on this issue.

Comment: remember visual studio is still a 32 bit application

Comment: analyze the dump with [DebugDiag2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924) analyzer

Comment: @ken-tucker I've debugged a ~5 GB 64 bit crash dump with VS 2015 before and it worked fine and I was able to view stack trace of my managed code.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thank you, I'll try DebugDiag2, By the way I've used Windbg to debug this crash dump, but its really hard to get call stack trace for managed code.

Comment: have you ever tried DebugDiag?

Comment: The DebugDiag v2 @magicandre1981 noted has been updated... get update3 here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=58210